# Excel sheet: Lock cell and write "1" on it based on a dropdown option

Tags: vba, excel

I want to lock cell B20 and write "1" on it if I choose a certain option ("T") on the dropdown of B18. If I choose any other option, I want to be able to fill it normally without any limitations. Here is the best code I tried:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ActiveSheet

If Target.Address = "$B$18" Then

    ws.Unprotect 

    Application.EnableEvents = False

    Target.Offset(1).Locked = Target.Value = "T"

    If Target.Value = "T" Then
        Target.Offset(1).Value = 1
    Else
        If Target.Offset(1).Value = 1 Then Target.Offset.Value = ""
    End If

    Application.EnableEvents = True

    ws.Protect 
End If


End Sub
```

This code is doing exactly what I want but its performing this on the cell B19 instead of B20.

Can somebody help me please?

Comment: What is `Target.Address = "$B18$1"`? Also, which cell do you want to set to `1` and based on which criteria?

Comment: A mistake, already fixed it. If B18 is "T", B20 should be "1" and locked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a bunch of code and text all saying different things in your question, so I based this code on your comment and the text of your question.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Target.Address = "$B$18" Then

        ws.Unprotect

        Application.EnableEvents = False

        Target.Offset(2).Locked = Target.Value = "T"

        If Target.Value = "T" Then
            Target.Offset(2).Value = 1
        Else
            If Target.Offset(2).Value = 1 Then Target.Offset.Value = ""
        End If

        Application.EnableEvents = True

        ws.Protect

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: There is an error at the line "If Target.Address = "$B$18" Then" when running. What I want is to lock the cell B20 with the shown value of "1" if the selection of B18 is "T"

Comment: changed the offset to 2 rows, its working, thank you :)

Comment: @EduardoRocha - I thought I adjusted the offset to 2 :). I must have only *thought* I did it :).  If it solves your problem, please mark as answered.

Comment: Well I just found more problems ahahah but thank you for your help, I will update the question

Comment: Actually it does not matter, it does what it matters, thank you very much :)